# How to convert Python dictionary to Scala equivalent (Map?)?

Tags: python, scala

I have a large (~700K) Python dictionary that has many sub-dictionaries, that I need to convert to whatever the appropriate equivalent is in Scala (Map?). It can be immutable. What's the easiest/quickest way to do this?

The dictionary is a hardcoded static dictionary in the source code of a larger Python script, which I'm converting to Scala, so I need to convert the dictionary to Scala as part of that. I'm not going to be changing the dictionary, it can be read-only (but doesn't have to be). It's a one-time conversion, not something I need to repeat. The Scala script will be run once a day on a Hadoop based big data platform.

I'm after the solution that is quickest to implement, ideally it will be at least reasonably efficient at run time too but that's not so important.

Here's the start of the dictionary in Python:

```py
MyData = {"590":{"69035":{"name":"Orange Carabe","id":"GLP01","realms":["epc.mnc001.mcc340.3gppnetwork.org"],"iso":"GP"},"59066":{"name":"Dauphin Telecom","id":"GLPDT","realms":["epc.mnc008.mcc340.3gppnetwork.org"],"iso":"GP"},"59077":{"name":"Dauphin Telecom","id":"GLPDT","realms":["epc.mnc008.mcc340.3gppnetwork.org"],"iso":"GP"},"69000":{"name":"Outremer Tlcom","id":"GUF01","realms":["epc.mnc002.mcc340.3gppnetwork.org"],"iso":"GP"},"6004":{"name":"Setel N.V.","id":"ANTUT","realms":["epc.mnc091.mcc362.3gppnetwork.org"],"iso":"AN"}, ....
```

I'm an experienced developer but new to both Python and Scala so looking for explicit solutions or code :)

Comment: Okay, then I would format the Python dictionary in a nice way and use multi caret features of my IDE to create a Scala Map equivalent. Or.. transform the dictionary to a JSON string then parse it with a Scala library of your choice as a Map in a REPL or worksheet, print the Map and copy it in your scala source code.

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks but it's that sort of thing I'm asking how to do really, a.) I'm not sure what Scala data structure is best, and b.) how do I explicitly do the conversion. I'm an experienced developer but new to both Python and Scala, so any explicit solutions or code are very helpful :) Thanks

Comment: If your dictionary contains similar data, I would go with `Map[String, SomeCaseClass]` in Scala to represent it.

Answer (score -1):

When you say you "have it in python", where is it coming from? Is python code generating it, or reading it from a file, or...?

I ask because my first move would be to try to just re-implement whatever is loading/generating it into the python runtime in scala instead. Otherwise you're adding unnecessary performance overhead (or worse - potentially reading in python, writing in python and then reading in scala, when you could just read in scala), and saddling yourself with the maintenance of both python and scala components going forward.

If that's not an option, there are libraries that will let you call python and scala functions from each other, but my bias would be to serialize it into a json from python and then deserialize that in scala.

Comment: _"just re-implement whatever"_ - how is that not "duplicating effort"?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that badly - duplicating computer effort, mostly, as you're doing both the work to load and then convert the data, when you could just load it. That said, I think in the long run it would also duplicate programmer effort as you have to maintain two components in two languages rather than just the one. Editing for clarity.

Comment: @EdwardPeters yes I'm trying to convert the whole Python script of which the dictionary is a part, into Scala. The dictionary is hardcoded into the Python script and I want the same in Scala. I've edited the original question with further clarity and an example of the data. Thanks

Comment: Okay - IMO, that's way too much data to have hard coded in any language. If you really, really want to have it hard coded in scala, then you'll want to do a bunch of careful find-and-replaces to switch definition formats, but I really, really don't advise it. Instead I would convert that to a json - there should be plenty of library support for that - and then just load it into scala.

Comment: BTW, I think if you *do* hard code it, you'll run into a method size limit. That's a JVM constant that is not configurable. You could work around it by either splitting it apart into multiple methods, or by creating it as a string and de-serializing it (strings go in the string pool and don't count towards method size), but that's another reason to have this in a config file you load instead.